# ASP.NET Core Cors WithExposedHeaders not working

Tags: asp.net-core, cors

I want my javascript client to be able to access my custom response header when using CORS.

This seems to be pretty simple, I just don't understand why it does not work!

Can anybody redeem me by saying why `WithExposedHeaders()` does not work?

```cs
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        ...
        services.AddCors(options =>
        {
            options.AddPolicy("MyCorsPolicy", builder =>
                {
                        builder
                        .WithOrigins("http://localhost:3000")
                        .AllowCredentials()
                        .AllowAnyMethod()
                        .AllowAnyHeader()
                        .WithExposedHeaders("X-My-Custom-Response-Header");
                    });
        });
        ...
    }
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
    {
        ...
        app.UseCors("MyCorsPolicy");
        ...
    }
}
```

The thing is, my custom response header is actually sends back in `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` response header, however, it is not sent back in preflight request with OPTIONS method.

Comment: Please clarify. Is your client able to read the value of the `X-My-Custom-Response-Header` header or not? If you're surprised not to see the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header in the preflight response, be aware that its absence is to expected: that header's place is in the actual response, not in the preflight response.

Answer (score -1):

It turned out that the problem was not on server-side at all. The problem was on client-side code!

I was using javascript `fetch() api` on client-side to invoke my `asp.net core web api`.

In the `response` object that `fetch` gives you back, you can use a `headers` property to access response headers.

I was using `response.headers.has()` to check whether my custom response header exists or not.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Headers/has

The frustration was that `response.headers.has()` always reported that there is no `X-My-Custom-Response-Header` among response headers.

When I looked into `response` object more closely, I noticed that, it DOES contain my custom response header and it was `response.headers.has()` that was reporting incorrectly.

I'm not sure if we can call this a bug in `headers.has()` api or not. For me, it did not work.